# Interpretation of sum of squares divided by sim

Tags: mean, weighted-mean

For the collection of numbers $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ consider the term,

$T_S =({\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2})/({\sum_{i=1}^n x_i})$

where $\forall i, x_i \in [0,1]$ . Is there any specific name for this term?

If not what is the interpretation of this term?

Example:

$T_{\{x_1,0,0,...,0\}} = x_1$

$T_{\{0.9,0.01\}} = 0.89$

$T_{\{0.9,0.3\}} = 0.75$

Comment: (1) What is "sim" in the title?  (2) See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_dispersion for a statistic that is, up to an additive function of $n$, equal to $T_S.$

Answer (score 1):

The statistic you have defined could be regarded as the ratio of the first two raw sample moments.  The first two raw sample moments are the **sample mean** and **sample mean-of-squares**, given respectively by:

$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \text{ } \tilde{x}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2.$$

Your statistic is equivalent to $T_S = \tilde{x}^2 / \bar{x}$, which is the ratio of these quantities.  I have not seen this statistic in use before, and it is a strange statistic to use, since it does not have any obviously useful properties.  There is no interpretation I am aware of other than saying that this is the ratio of the first two raw sample moments.